# Coding in third-party EDI interface

Tags: edi

first time posting here so please bare with. I'm working on a project with a third-party software provider in which they have a built in EDI interface. They have installed some templates that parse the data that comes through in an .xml file and dumps all the data into the correct tables and columns in our database.

These templates were installed about 4 years ago, much before my time. And anyone at the time who was involved in the project has since moved on, with no documentation on what programming language this is or how everything works together. It's a pretty terrible interface, there is no way to debug, or see what the code is doing without sending the same dummy data over and over again, until I can figure out what it's doing.

tl;dr: I have some code that I'm working on and have no resources or documentation on what language it is or how it's working from start to finish. Can someone help me identify please? If I call the third party for help, they will charge my company $225/hour just to look at the code. They say it will take them 4 hours to look at it. Maybe a few more hours to fix it.

Example of code:

```
if (N702<>"" or N711 <> "" or N715<>"" or N722<>"") {
CLEAR("edi_stop_note");  
edi_stop_note$comment_type <- "OC";
N711_desc<-qual_lookup("40",N711);  
edi_stop_note$comments <-concat("Trlr: ",N702," Desc: ",N711_desc," Len: ",N715," Type: ",N722);
ADDNOTE("edi_stop","edi_stop_note") ;
};
```

Another example:

```
LineCnt <- "-1"; 
Stop_No <- "0";
Stop_Seq <- "0"; 
CLEAR("edi_order");
CLEAR("edi_stop");
edi_order$shipper_stop_id <-edi_stop$id;
edi_order$version <- edi_version;
edi_order$gs_date_time <- date_time(gs04_date, gs05_time); 
edi_order$gs06_group_cntlno  <- gs06_incntlno; 
edi_order$st02_trxset_cntlno <- st02_cntlno; 
edi_order$partner_id  <- gs02_partner;
edi_order$reply_created <- "N";
edi_order$isa13_intr_cntlno <- isa13_intr_cntlno;
edi_order$direction <- "I";
edi_order$alt_partner_id <- alt_partner_id;
TIME <- cur_time("4");
DATE <- cur_date("6") ; 
B204 <- "";
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Basically, my question is does anyone know what code they are using so that I can find the documentation behind it, to make heads or tails of what syntax to use and what the variables do. Like, there is one variable that I keep seeing pop up called 'CUR_DE' @Peanut

Comment: @joefred16 I'm going to make a guess that the variable is referencing the EDI document.  The CUR is the segment in the document, and the DE represents the CUR01.  DE means "depositor" according to the standard.  The developer kept variable names sane in line with EDI document.  So the CUR02 will be the value that you want to map to the XML.  The CUR01 describes the CUR02.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for the insight. I thought I looked through all the EDI documentation I could find but when I Googled the variable names, nothing came up. Do you have a link that you can provide to the document that you are referencing, please?

Comment: @joefred16 variables are made up arbitrarily by the developer.  When you look at an EDI document, you reference it by SEGMENT and then Element.  So if you had: N1*ST*TEST*92*12345~ , then the N101 would be ST.  The N102 would be TEST, and the N104 would be 12345.  Download EDI Notepad from Liaison to help you make sense of the source data, then apply it to the target.  My guess is that the developer of whatever code base you're working on tried to make his life easier by naming the variable in the code the same as the EDI element.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for this. I will take it and see what I can figure out. Again, is this document out on the web anywhere? I could not find when Googling the last 3 days

Comment: @joefred16 When I say EDI "document", that just references the file.  If you want to edit your question and post your EDI file there we might be able to tell you what you're looking at.